# Php mysql database item name call from another database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an quetion about how to do asociation with 2 tables in database with id and item name

I have 2 databases one is :

```
CREATE TABLE `alchimie` (
`id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_potiune` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`nume_potiune` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',
`nivel_potiune` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
`nivel_caracter` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
`obiecte_necesare` tinytext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this is the table with data inserted

[Image 1 http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/4522/55040113.png](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/4522/55040113.png)

A part of the second database is

```
 CREATE TABLE `iteme` (
 `obiect` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `nume` text collate utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  ------------------------------------------------
 PRIMARY KEY  (`obiect`),
 KEY `tip` (`tip`,`pret_cumparare`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 

 (obiect in my case is id )
```

I dont know how to call from php id's to asociate with names (nume) from the second database

Instead of 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 (writed in db) separated by ' , ' 
I want to apear the name of the items

Example :

```
 INSERT INTO `iteme` VALUES ('1', 'Name of item 1', .....');
 INSERT INTO `iteme` VALUES ('2', 'Name of item 2', .......');
 INSERT INTO `iteme` VALUES ('3', 'Name of item 3 ', .......');
```

AND

```
 INSERT INTO `alchimie` VALUES ('1', '100', 'Fusar ', '1', '1', '1, 2, 3');
```

And it will apear at "obiecte necesare"

[Image 2 http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/1614/78551339.png](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/1614/78551339.png)

I hope that this time I could finally make you understand what i'm trying to do but fail

Comment: I don't follow what you're after. Try to eliminate any code or mysql structure that is not absolutely relevant to your question.

Comment: all the codes are needed to explain. I have a database X with tablesdata 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 etc. In another database Y i have the names of some items. I want a code that if i change in X from 1 to 9 the name to change also

Comment: Show your table structure and the code that isn't working -- there is a lot of other information here (you say yourself that something is just an example). The reason you aren't getting answers is because it isn't clear what you're trying to do. If you want help, you'll clean up your question. Or, leave it how it is and hope someone can make sense of this mess. Up to you.

Comment: i tried my best , i posted pictures, i made it very simple. Hope that this time is ok for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need a column in `iteme` table to reference to `alchimie` in my following example I gave it a name `alchimie_id`.

Now `LEFT JOIN`, `GROUP BY`, and `GROUP_CONCAT()` will do the trick with a query

```sql
SELECT a.nume_potiune, 
       a.nivel_potiune,
       a.nivel_caracter,
       i.obiecte_necesare
  FROM alchimie a LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT alchimie_id,
         GROUP_CONCAT(nume) obiecte_necesare
    FROM iteme
   GROUP BY alchimie_id
) i
    ON a.id = i.alchimie_id
```

Sample output:

```
|  NUME_POTIUNE | NIVEL_POTIUNE | NIVEL_CARACTER |                          OBIECTE_NECESARE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         Fusar |             1 |              1 | Name of item1,Name of item2,Name of item3 |
|      Caracuda |             1 |              1 |                                    (null) |
| Tipar Chiscar |             2 |              1 |                                    (null) |
|         Salau |             2 |              2 |                                    (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a702d/2)** demo.

Comment: i readed the code, tried to integrate, but i think something is wrong, , in my table at "obiecte necesare" or it leaves blank , or Resource id #17 , or Resource id #16.

i made       
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT a.nume_potiune ....

And to call it

       echo ".$query["obiecte_necesare"].";